# BP assessment tool in Shiny cannot find function "ranges"

Tags: r, shiny

I'm attempting to build a blood pressure assessment tool in Shiny that will provide guidance relative to a person's BP numbers.

Here is my ui.R
    library(shiny)

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Blood pressure assessment"),

    fluidRow(
            column(3,
                   h3("Systolic BP"),
                   h4("The first/top number"),
                   sliderInput("x1", label = "mm Hg", min = 90, max = 200,
                               value = 90, animate = TRUE)),
            column(3,
                   h3("Diastolic BP"),
                   h4("The second/bottom number"),
                   sliderInput("x2", label = "mm HG", min = 50, max = 120, 
                               value = 50, animate = TRUE))),
            column(3,
                   h4("Your range"),
                   verbatimTextOutput("ranges")),
            column(3,
                   br(),
                   actionButton("submit", "Submit"))))
```

And here is my server.R file

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    function(ranges) { reactiveValues(normal = "Normal Range",
                             caution = "Caution Range = Prehypertension",
                             high = "High Range = Stage 1 Hypertension",
                             very = "Very High Range = Stage 2 Hypertension")}
    dataInput <- reactive({
    if(input$x1 > 160){return()} else{
            if(input$x2 > 100){return("very")}
    }

    if(input$x1 == 140:159){return()} else{
            if(input$x2 == 90:99){return("high")}
    }

    if(input$x1 == 120:139){return()} else{
            if(input$x2 == 80:89){return("caution")}
    }
    if(input$x1 < 120){return()} else{
            if(input$x2 > 80) {return("normal")}
    }
    })

    observeEvent(input$submit, {

            output$ranges <- renderPrint({ranges(input$x1, input$x2)})

            })
}
    )
```

The response that comes back when I try to run the app is

```
Error in func() : could not find function "ranges"
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong. I have a suspicion that I've made it more complicated than it needs to be or that I'm missing something really obvious. This is my first shiny app.

Comment: Inside of `renderPrint` you are trying to use the function `ranges`. It doesn't seem that you defined it anywhere properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue here is, that you are not defining a proper function to find the state of one's BP.

The following function gives you output dependent on two figures of input. I'm not sure though, if it is completely correct. Your code is not very clear in that sense: Has a person with `systolic == 130` and `diastolic == 70` `"Prehypertension"`, or nothing?

I defined the function below as follows: If both values are below 120 and 80, respectively, `"Normal Range"` is returned. If either value is above 160 or 100, respectively, `"Very High Range = Stage 2 Hypertension"` is returned. If either value is between 121 and 139 or 80 and 89, respectively, `"Prehypertension"` is returned, and so forth. Is that how it should be?

```r
# define function which gives finds blood pressure state
find_bp_state <- function(systolic, diastolic) {
  if (systolic < 120 & diastolic < 80) {
    return("Normal Range")
  } else if (systolic > 160 | diastolic > 100) {
    return("Very High Range = Stage 2 Hypertension")
  } else if (systolic %in% c(121:139) | diastolic %in% c(80:89)) {
    return("Caution Range = Prehypertension")
  } else if (systolic %in% c(140:159) | diastolic %in% c(90:99)) {
    return("High Range = Stage 1 Hypertension")
  }
}

# test function
find_bp_state(130, 82)
#> [1] "Caution Range = Prehypertension"
```

After that you can create your app which will give you expected results, depending on how you defined your function above.

For demonstration purposes the following code works in a single file.

```
library(shiny)

find_bp_state <- function(systolic, diastolic) {
  if (systolic < 120 & diastolic < 80) {
    return("Normal Range")
  } else if (systolic > 160 | diastolic > 100) {
    return("Very High Range = Stage 2 Hypertension")
  } else if (systolic %in% c(121:139) | diastolic %in% c(80:89)) {
    return("Caution Range = Prehypertension")
  } else if (systolic %in% c(140:159) | diastolic %in% c(90:99)) {
    return("High Range = Stage 1 Hypertension")
  }
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Blood pressure assessment"),

  fluidRow(
    column(3,
           h3("Systolic BP"),
           h4("The first/top number"),
           sliderInput("x1", label = "mm Hg", min = 90, max = 200,
                       value = 90, animate = TRUE)),
    column(3,
           h3("Diastolic BP"),
           h4("The second/bottom number"),
           sliderInput("x2", label = "mm HG", min = 50, max = 120, 
                       value = 50, animate = TRUE))),
  column(3,
         h4("Your range"),
         verbatimTextOutput("ranges")),
  column(3,
         br(),
         actionButton("submit", "Submit")))

server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    output$ranges <- renderPrint({
      systolic <- input$x1
      diastolic <- input$x2

      print(find_bp_state(systolic = systolic, diastolic = diastolic))
    })
  })

  }

shinyApp(server = server, ui = ui)
```

In case you want to have a `ui.R` and a `server.R`, your code could be as follows:

**ui.R**:

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Blood pressure assessment"),

  fluidRow(
    column(3,
           h3("Systolic BP"),
           h4("The first/top number"),
           sliderInput("x1", label = "mm Hg", min = 90, max = 200,
                       value = 90, animate = TRUE)),
    column(3,
           h3("Diastolic BP"),
           h4("The second/bottom number"),
           sliderInput("x2", label = "mm HG", min = 50, max = 120, 
                       value = 50, animate = TRUE))),
  column(3,
         h4("Your range"),
         verbatimTextOutput("ranges")),
  column(3,
         br(),
         actionButton("submit", "Submit")
  )
))
```

**server.R**:

```
library(shiny)

find_bp_state <- function(systolic, diastolic) {
  if (systolic < 120 & diastolic < 80) {
    return("Normal Range")
  } else if (systolic > 160 | diastolic > 100) {
    return("Very High Range = Stage 2 Hypertension")
  } else if (systolic %in% c(121:139) | diastolic %in% c(80:89)) {
    return("Caution Range = Prehypertension")
  } else if (systolic %in% c(140:159) | diastolic %in% c(90:99)) {
    return("High Range = Stage 1 Hypertension")
  }
}

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    observeEvent(input$submit, {
      output$ranges <- renderPrint({
        systolic <- input$x1
        diastolic <- input$x2

        print(find_bp_state(systolic = systolic, diastolic = diastolic))
      })
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you so very much. I was definitely making things way too complicated. Much appreciation!

Comment: @LesleyLathrop You can show your appreciation by accepting the answer ;)

Comment: I would be happy to do so, but I'm not sure how. I'm a newbie here. :) I did try to upvote it, but I don't see where to go to note that the question has been resolved.

Comment: @LesleyLathrop With StackOverflow you can google almost anything: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I FINALLY found out how to accept an answer! Sorry for the delay.